# How to use CSS border image for a 3x3 table such that there is only 1 border between every 2 cells?

Tags: css, css-tables, border-image

I have been experimenting with the border-image property and am trying to make a 3x3 grid with a border on the outside and a border between every cell. The problem is if I use the border-image property on the table cells like so:

```
td {
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-image-source: url(https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6009/border-image-2.png);
    border-image-slice: 33% 33% 33% 33%;
    border-image-repeat: round round;
    border-image-outset: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

There ends up being two borders between each cell. See  http://codepen.io/katieyang/pen/RpKpNW?editors=0100 if it's not quite clear what I mean.

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've run into one of the many quirks of styling tables. With ordinary borders, you can solve this by using [`border-collapse: collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse), but that appears to defeat `border-image` on table cells, at least in some browsers.*

If I were you, I'd solve this by styling an `::after` pseudo-element rather than the `<td>` elements themselves.

You can see it working in the snippet below, but here are the important parts:

1. `border-collapse: collapse;` on the `<table>`
2. A transparent border of the desired width on the `<td>`s and `position: relative;` so a pseudo-element can be positioned absolutely within
3. An `::after` pseudo-element on each `<td>` with `position: absolute;` and positioned to cover the `<td>` and its border
4. Top and left `border-image`s on each pseudo-element, a right `border-image` on the last pseudo-element of each row, and a bottom `border-image` on the pseudo-elements of the bottom row.

In the snippet I've added some `:hover` styles to show where the pseudo-elements and their borders are positioned.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

td {
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}

td::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  border: 10px solid blue;
  border-image-source: url(//mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6009/border-image-2.png);
  border-image-slice: 33%;
  border-image-repeat: round;
  border-image-outset: 0;
}

td:hover::after {
  /* for demonstration only */
  border-image: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.33);
}

td:not(:last-child)::after {
  border-right: 0;
}

tr:not(:last-child) td::after {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="box">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*The current [`border-image` spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#border-image-tables) says:

> The ‘`border-image`’ properties apply to the border of tables and inline tables that have ‘`border-collapse`’ set to ‘`collapse`’. However, this specification does not define how such an image border is rendered. In particular, it does not define how the image border interacts with the borders of cells, rows and row groups at the edges of the table.

...but MDN says it applies to "all elements, except internal table elements when `border-collapse` is `collapse`," which seems to be the current behavior in Chrome and Firefox, at least.

Comment: That's really amazing. I never would have though of a solution like this. Thanks especially for the :hover styles, it made things super clear!